# Unable to get json info from controller when using Angular's $http

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

So I am trying to get some info from an action in my controller.

The action currently looks like this:

```
def index
        @users = User.all

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json { render json: @users }
        end
end
```

This index page is set as the root in `routes.rb`

Now, this is how my AngularJs controller looks like, from where I am trying to get the info:

```
@test.controller 'TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', ($scope, $location, $http) ->
    $scope.data = []

    $http.get('/')
    .success (data) =>
        $scope.data = data
        console.log($scope.data)
    .error (data) ->
        console.log('error!')
]
```

And when I load the root page I only get the whole page loaded as html in the Javascript console log.

So am I missing something here that needs to be done in order to get the action `index` respond in json for my AngularJs controller?

Server log:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-28 18:02:26 +0200
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."followed_id" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = $1  [["follower_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = $1  [["followed_id", 1]]
  Rendered users/_stats.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 137ms (Views: 134.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

Comment: what errors you are getting? did you check your rails app server log?

Comment: I am getting no errors. My problem is just that the controller is giving my AngularJs controller data in html not json. If I print out the data i get from the request, it's the whole page in html.

Comment: can you try this in your controller?
 `format.json { render json: @users.to_json }`

Comment: Still the same thing.

Comment: okey, can you do one thing?
can you give the server log when your angular's controller create request to you rails app? I can see there how the request is sending.

Comment: Updated the question with the log. From log it looks like it was never even asked. Also worth nothing that because of angular,  the same thing  is done twice in the log. So it is basically loading the page 2 times.

Comment: checkout this line:
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML

Comment: Yes, but how do I get it to respond as JSON then for the action that I call in my AngularJS controller?

Comment: something like `vistors/index.json` or you need to tell angular's $http.get to get json

Comment: so if you now have a visitors/index.json then why not $http.get(/index.json).success, you need to adjust the inside of .get()

Comment: That seemed to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by not doing the query to `'/'` route but instead to `'/users.json'`. Even if you do something like this: `'/.json'`, it will not work.